# Password and username in distinct collections (Spring security)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security

I'm trying to implement authentication with Spring Security and my problem is that I'm using a MongoDB base where the username and the associated password are in two distinct collections. So when I implement UserDetails, I can't return the password properly. Here is what I've tried:

```
package com.example.springmongo.user;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2217225560457250699L;

    @Autowired
    private UserPassService userPassService;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(value = "iduser")
    private Long iduser;

    @Field(value = "name_complete")
    private String name_complete;

    @Field(value = "mail")
    private String mail;

    @Field(value = "active")
    private Double active;

    @Field(value = "creationDate")
    private String creationDate;

    @Field(value = "last_login")
    private String last_login;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String id, Long iduser, String name_complete, String mail, Double active, String creationDate, String last_login) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.iduser = iduser;
        this.name_complete = name_complete;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.active = active;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.last_login = last_login;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getIduser() {
        return iduser;
    }

    public void setIduser(Long iduser) {
        this.iduser = iduser;
    }

    public String getName_complete() {
        return name_complete;
    }

    public void setName_complete(String name_complete) {
        this.name_complete = name_complete;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public Double getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Double active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getLast_login() {
        return last_login;
    }

    public void setLast_login(String last_login) {
        this.last_login = last_login;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + this.name_complete + ", mail: " + this.mail + ", id: " + this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.userPassService.getUserPassword(this.iduser);
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.getMail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        if (this.getActive() != null && this.getActive().equals(1.0)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        if (this.getActive() != null && this.getActive().equals(1.0)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        if (this.getActive() != null && this.getActive().equals(1.0)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        if (this.getActive() != null && this.getActive().equals(1.0)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't access my UserPassService from an entity like this. So how can I access the password ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why do you need the password for? Usually this hash will be required for very few specific operations and in most of the cases the tuple will be passed to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter etc.

Comment: The function getPassword() is used by the authentificationProvider to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `@Autowired` on spring components in entity class as a field. Use like this ;

```
private transient UserPassService userPassService;
```

and add setter method of this ;

```
@Autowired
public void setUserPassService(UserPassService userPassService) {
    this.userPassService = userPassService;
}
```

Beaware of creatation of `Entity` class with `new` is making this service is null. If you create with `new` , call `setUserPassService` method with autowired object of UserPassService.